# Redirect user to an arbitrary application protocol (used by Android app)

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, redirect, 301-redirect

I have an Android application that declares an intent using a in-house protocol. You can launch it by opening a webpage that contains a link to :

```
myapplication://foo-bar
```

I want to an URL on my website that will anwser a 301 Redirect to that custom, in-house, made-up protocol. The idea is that our Android application will be launched when the user clicks on that link (the app is already installed).

I could simply add an anchro link in an HTML page, but I can't modify the HTML. I have to use Apache. I tried this mod_rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule "^/app$" myapplication://foo-bar [R=permanent,L]
```

But it always prepend the host name in front, so I get this in the Location header:

```
Location: https://example.com/myapplication://foo-bar
```

How can I instruct mod_rewrite to use the URL as-is (`myapplication://foo-bar`)?

Comment: Why don't you just set an additional intent filter on the HTTP URL? This is what many apps do in order to launch their app when someone touches a web link.